# Get Lokalize Item By Key Name instead of Key Id

Tags: rest, localization, lokalise

We are using lokalise REST api to get the translation from the key id. `GET https://api.lokalise.com/api2/projects/{project_id:branch}/keys/{key_id}` https://app.lokalise.com/api2docs/curl/#resource-keys

The problem is that we don't know the id of the resource but only key name of the resource. How do get the translation from key-name (like welcome_message) instead of key-d(like 123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Lokalise team support. I need to use `filter_keys` to filter data from all keys, `include_translations` to get the translation and `filter_translation_lang_ids` to get specfic languge (though the language id is not ISO standard but Lokalise internal language id). Here is an example,

Example below,

```
https://api.lokalise.com/api2/projects/project_id/keys?filter_keys=key_name&include_translations=1&filter_translation_lang_ids=123
```